# Disable button after one week

Tags: python, django

I made a page where you can place a comment. You can also delete your comment with a delete button. What I want is that after you placed a comment you have one week to delete it. So after a week I want to hide the delete button.

When trying to do this I'm getting this error:
'<' not supported between instances of 'datetime.timedelta' and 'int'

view:

```
 class TechnologyDetailView(DetailView):
 model = Technology

 def get_queryset(self):
    group_permissions = 
 Permission.objects.filter(group__user=self.request.user)
    query = Technology.objects.filter(pk=self.kwargs['pk'], 
 is_active=True, permission__in=group_permissions)

    for tech in query:
        comments = Comment.objects.filter(technology=tech)
        now = datetime.now()

        for comment in comments:
            comment.timestamp = datetime.strptime('Jun 1 2005 1:33PM', 
 '%b %d %Y %I:%M%p')
            print(comment.timestamp)

            age = now - comment.timestamp

            if age < 604800:
                comment.is_removable = True
            else:
                comment.is_removable = False

    return query
```

template:

```
 <h3>Comments</h3>
                {% for comment in technology.comment_set.all %}
                    <div class="row" style="border-bottom-style:solid; 
 border-bottom-width:1px; border-color:gray;">
                        <h6 style="font-weight:bold">Written by {{ 
 comment.user.name }}
                            on {{ comment.timestamp }}</h6>
                        <span>{{ comment.content|breaks }}</span>
                            <p>{{ comment.timestamp | timesince }}</p>


                        {% if comment.user == request.user %}
                            <a class="modal-trigger right" 
 href="#modal_{{ comment.pk }}">Delete Comment</a>
                        {% endif %}
                     <div id="modal_{{ comment.pk  }}" class="modal">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <iframe frameborder="0" 
 id="encoder_iframe" height=300px width="100%" src="{% url 'delete-
 comment' comment.pk %}"></iframe>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                {% empty %}
                    <p>There are no comments</p>
                {% endfor %}
                <br>
                <h5>Add new Comment</h5>
                <iframe frameborder="0" id="encoder_iframe" 
height=300px width="100%" src="{% url 'add-comment' technology.pk %}">
</iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Model:

```
# Comment model
class Comment(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)
technology = models.ForeignKey(Technology, null=True)
parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True)
content = models.TextField(null=True)
timestamp = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: This would be better as a method on the Comment model, which you can call in your template - then you wouldn't need to iterate in your view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`age` is not an integer, but a `timedelta` instance. You need to change the comparison to:

```
if age.total_seconds() < 604800:
```

or

```
if age < timedelta(seconds=604800):
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really a django problem, its a python date time problem:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> then = datetime.now()
>>> now = datetime.now()
```

The difference between two datetimes is a timedelta:

```
>>> now - then
datetime.timedelta(0, 7, 452120)
```

which you cant compare with a number:

```
>>> (now - then) < 5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can't compare datetime.timedelta to int
```

But you can convert to seconds (and minutes etc) and compare:

```
>>> (now - then).seconds < 5
False
>>> (now - then).seconds 
7
```

The possible django issue further down the line is that even though you might not have a button for deleting old comments, that doesn't stop a client sending a delete request - so make sure you trap attempted deletes of old comments **in the view handler on the server**.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I will sure do follow your tip about the view handler!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compare int and datetime. Try something like:

```
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()
from datetime import timedelta
time_to_delete = timedelta(weeks=1)
comment1 = datetime(2018, 1, 15)
comment2 = datetime(2018, 1, 2)
now - time_to_delete <= comment1  # True
now - time_to_delete <= comment2  # False
```